# Problem loading cram_physics_utils

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when I try to load some asd files in rosemacs I encounter the following problem. No idea how to solve, need help!!!

```
; g++ -m64 -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include -I/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/cram_core/3rdparty/cffi/cffi-dev/ -o ~/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.0.50-linux-amd64~/ros/fuerte_workspace/stable_stacks/cram_highlevel/cram_physics_utils/src/assimp-grovel ~/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.0.50-linux-amd64~/ros/fuerte_workspace/stable_stacks/cram_highlevel/cram_physics_utils/src/assimp-grovel.c
; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition
```

I am using Fuerte on Ubuntu10.04X64, cram_highlevel is cloned yesterday.

contents of the *inferior-lisp*

```
> STYLE-WARNING:
>   Implicitly creating new generic function STREAM-READ-CHAR-WILL-HANG-P.
>; loading #P"～/.slime/fasl/2012-06-19/sbcl-1.0.50-linux-x86-64/swank-match.fasl"
>; loading #P"～/.slime/fasl/2012-06-19/sbcl-1.0.50-linux-x86-64/swank-rpc.fasl"
>; loading #P"～/.slime/fasl/2012-06-19/sbcl-1.0.50-linux-x86-64/swank.fasl"
>WARNING: These Swank interfaces are unimplemented:
> (DISASSEMBLE-FRAME SLDB-BREAK-AT-START SLDB-BREAK-ON-RETURN)


>; file: ～/.swank.lisp
>; in: SETF SWANK:*GLOBALLY-REDIRECT-IO*
>;     (SETF SWANK:*GLOBALLY-REDIRECT-IO* T)
>; ==>
>;   (SETQ SWANK:*GLOBALLY-REDIRECT-IO* T)
>; 
>; caught WARNING:
>;   undefined variable: SWANK:*GLOBALLY-REDIRECT-IO*
>; 
>; compilation unit finished
>;   Undefined variable:
>;     SWANK:*GLOBALLY-REDIRECT-IO*
>;   caught 1 WARNING condition
>;; Swank started at port: 57838.
57838
>* STYLE-WARNING: redefining SWANK::SYMBOL-INDENTATION in DEFUN
STYLE-WARNING: redefining SWANK::MACRO-INDENTATION in DEFUN
```

Debug window

```
Component "" not found
   [Condition of type ASDF:MISSING-COMPONENT]

Restarts:
 0: [ABORT] Abort compilation.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [TERMINATE-THREAD] Terminate this thread (#<THREAD "new-repl-thread" RUNNING {100305B5C1}>)

Backtrace:
  0: ((LAMBDA ()))
  1: ((LAMBDA ()))
      [No Locals]
  2: (ASDF::CALL-WITH-SYSTEM-DEFINITIONS #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA #) {100323AB19}>)
  3: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD ASDF:OPERATE (T T)) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> ASDF:LOAD-OP "")
  4: ((SB-PCL::EMF ASDF:OPERATE) #<unused argument> #<unused argument> ASDF:LOAD-OP "")
  5: ((LAMBDA ()))
  6: ((FLET SWANK-BACKEND:CALL-WITH-COMPILATION-HOOKS) #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA #) {100323AA99}>)
  7: (SWANK::OPERATE-ON-SYSTEM "" SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::LOAD-OP)
  8: ((LAMBDA ()))
  9: (SWANK::MEASURE-TIME-INTERVAL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA #) {100323A9D9}>)
 10: (SWANK::COLLECT-NOTES #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA #) {100323A9A9}>)
 11: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SWANK:OPERATE-ON-SYSTEM-FOR-EMACS "" (QUOTE SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::LOAD-OP)) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 12: (EVAL (SWANK:OPERATE-ON-SYSTEM-FOR-EMACS "" (QUOTE SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::LOAD-OP)))
 13: (SWANK:EVAL-FOR-EMACS (SWANK:OPERATE-ON-SYSTEM-FOR-EMACS "" 'SWANK-IO-PACKAGE::LOAD-OP) "COMMON-LISP-USER" 29)
 14: (SWANK::PROCESS-REQUESTS NIL)
 15: ((LAMBDA ()))
 16: ((LAMBDA ()))
 17: (SWANK-BACKEND::CALL-WITH-BREAK-HOOK #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA #) {1003060119}>)
 18: ((FLET SWANK-BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK) #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA #) {1003060119}>)
 19: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS ((*STANDARD-OUTPUT* . #) (*STANDARD-INPUT* . #) (*TRACE-OUTPUT* . #) (*ERROR-OUTPUT* . #) (*DEBUG-IO* . #) (*QUERY-IO* . #) ...) #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA #) {1003060139}>)
 20: (SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS #<SWANK::MULTITHREADED-CONNECTION {1003B98CC1}> NIL)
 21: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-[BLOCK414]419))
 22: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK))
 23: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-[CALL-WITH-MUTEX]301))
 24: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX ..)
 25: (SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION)
 26: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
 27: ("foreign function: new_thread_trampoline")
```

**New problem after the patch, when I load cram_plan_library**

```
; compiling file "～/ros/fuerte_workspace/stable_stacks/cram_highlevel/cram_plan_library/src/at-location.lisp" (written 14 NOV 2012 01:44:02 PM):
; compiling (IN-PACKAGE :PLAN-LIB)
; compiling (DEFVAR *AT-LOCATION-LOCK* ...)
; compiling (DEFCONSTANT +AT-LOCATION-RETRY-COUNT+ ...)
; compiling (CRAM-PROJECTION:DEFINE-SPECIAL-PROJECTION-VARIABLE *AT-LOCATION-LOCK* ...)
; compiling (DEFUN LOCATION-DESIGNATOR-REACHED ...)
; compiling (DEFMACRO WITH-EQUATE-FLUENT ...)
;
; compilation aborted because of fatal error:
;   SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR at 3626 (line 75, column 45) on #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
;                                                                        for "file ～/ros/fuerte_workspace/stable_stacks/cram_highlevel/cram_plan_library/src/at-location.lisp"
;                                                                        {10044AC5E1}>:
;     Symbol "WITH-TRANSFORMS-CHANGED-CALLBACK" not found in the CL-TF package.
;   
; compilation aborted after 0:00:00.057
WARNING:
   COMPILE-FILE warned while performing #<COMPILE-OP NIL {1003BAB741}> on
   #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cram-plan-library" "src" "at-location">.
; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 2 fatal ERROR conditions
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48375/problem-loading-cram_physics_utils/) by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-15**:
Is this really the complete output after the error occurred? To improve readability (newlines don't seem to be displayed correctly), can you please change the formatting of your code from citation to code? Just mark the code and press Ctrl-k.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-15**:
Ok. More questions :) For me, the inferior-lisp buffer doesn't really show anything useful. But since you got a compilation error, I guess emacs entered the debugger. Can you please provide the contents of the debugger window? It should contain the actual compiler error message.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-15**:
The error message above doesn't seem to be related to assimp. It rather looks like you tried to load an asdf file with name "".

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2012-11-15**:
Thank you Lorenz, your patch indeed works!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-15**:
Your second issue is completely unrelated to cram_physics_utils. Please open a new question and re-mark my answer as correct if it was. I will answer there.

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2012-11-15**:
Done, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you do not have assimp installed. I just added the corresponding rosdep rule and pushed it to cram_highlevel. Try installing it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libassimp-dev
```

If that doesn't help, please **edit** your answer to provide more information. Please provide more lines around the actual error, maybe it contains something useful that helps debugging the problem. Also, please provide information such as the ROS version you are using and the version of Ubuntu and make sure you have a look at the [support page](http://ros.org/wiki/Support).

**Update**: Do you maybe have openrave installed? Its requires version 3 of assimp which unfortunately conflicts with version 2 provided by Ubuntu and used by ROS Fuerte. If you need to use assimp3, apply the following patch in cram_highlevel:

```
diff --git a/cram_physics_utils/src/assimp-grovel.lisp b/cram_physics_utils/src/assimp-grovel.lisp
index e1b6413..8c43062 100644
--- a/cram_physics_utils/src/assimp-grovel.lisp
+++ b/cram_physics_utils/src/assimp-grovel.lisp
@@ -28,11 +28,11 @@
 ;;; POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 ;;;
 
-(include "assimp/assimp.h")
-(include "assimp/aiMesh.h")
-(include "assimp/aiScene.h")
-(include "assimp/aiMaterial.h")
-(include "assimp/aiPostProcess.h")
+(include "assimp/types.h")
+(include "assimp/mesh.h")
+(include "assimp/scene.h")
+(include "assimp/material.h")
+(include "assimp/postprocess.h")
 
 (in-package :physics-utils)
```

Just copy-paste it to a file, e.g. ~/assimp3.patch. Then execute the following commands:

```
roscd cram_highlevel
patch -p1 < ~/assimp3.patch
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0